# Convert CSV to Matrix

Tags: arrays, bash, csv, sorting, matrix

I'm trying to convert values from the first column in a CSV file and arranging those values from lowest latitude/highest longitude (southwest) to highest latitude/lowest longitude (northeast) into a matrix.

This CSV file has hundreds of lines of data.

I know that I'm going to need to use `sort` to accomplish this but, I'm not sure if what I have so far is enough.

**Sample:**

```
18,49.000,-96.000
30,41.000,-109.000
65,31.000,-80.000
25,47.000,-75.000
45,37.000,-90.000
60,30.000,-100.000
70,30.000,-118.000
...
...
...
```

**Bash Code:**

```
sort -t',' -nr -k2 -k3
```

**Result:**

```
18,49.000,-96.000
25,47.000,-75.000
30,41.000,-109.000
45,37.000,-90.000
65,31.000,-80.000
60,30.000,-100.000
70,30.000,-118.000
```

**Sample Conceptual Graphic:**

[image]

**Expected Matrix Setup:**

```
      18
             25  
   30
         45
70   60
            65
```

Comment: The [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Comment: What's the target? Do you want to create a SVG graphic?

Comment: @Cyrus, the target is a `.dat` file of rows and columns of 1st column data, sorted from lower left (southwest) to upper right (northeast)

Answer (score 0):

If it is acceptable to use general programming language like Perl, try something like:

```
perl -e '
while (<>) {
    ($code, $lat, $long) = split(/,/);
    $lats{$lat}++;
    $longs{$long}++;
    $map{$lat, $long} = $code;
}

for $lat (sort {$b <=> $a} keys %lats) {
    for $long (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %longs) {
            $str = $map{$lat, $long} || "  ";
            print $str . " ";
    }
    print "\n";
}' samplefile
```

and the result looks like:

```
         18
                  25
   30
            45
               65
70    60
```

Note that #65 is not southernmost in your sample data.
Hope this helps.